# SKProductsRequest crashing app at startup with iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, crash, startup

Reports of our app crashing started flooding in last night. Many users who upgraded to 7.0.3 had the app crash at startup. Analyzing the itunes crash logs it was due to the app getting killed for taking too long to startup. Apparently the call to check for available in-app purchases is what was causing the crash.
We removed all in-app purchases from sale and now users are reporting that the app is now working.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

// earlier stuff...
    [self requestProductData]; // ask for in-app purchase localized prices/names
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self]; // process any   pending transactions

// more stuff...
}

- (void) requestProductData
{
    NSMutableSet * prodSet = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithCapacity:10] autorelease];

    StoreItem * curStoreItem;
    for(int j=0; j<[storeArr count]; j++) {
        curStoreItem = [storeArr objectAtIndex:j];
        [prodSet addObject:curStoreItem.productID];
    }


    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:prodSet];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, we make the call to request product data.  Do we need to be doing this in another thread?  Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Why do you request product data on app launch? I do it when the user actually wants to perform a purchase.

Comment: No good reason except for that back in the day (ios 3.x or earlier when we first added in-app purchase) that was what the apple example code did. We haven't touched that part of the code in years. I guess it's time :).  Sounds like moving this to a later stage avoids the issue we are having.  I'll give it a try - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Given that a user will rarely make an in-app purchase compared to the number of times they use your app, it is a real waste of resources to load the product data on every app launch.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - I believe you have solved the issue. I guess apple changed the timing with 7.0.3 of this server call and triggered the crash, but as you point out the real issue is that we shouldn't be making this call at startup. If you post an answer I'll mark the question as answered.  Cheers.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't really answer the question. It works around the issue though. :)

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you ever come up with a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this in two ways, addressing the immediate live app crashing and then actually addressing the coding error that triggered it.

The iOS 7.0.3 update added a latency to the call to apple servers which return in-app product data.  Since we were making the product request call from didFinishLaunching our app was being killed for not starting up quickly enough.

To address the live app crashing we temporarily removed all in app purchases for the app from sale. 
Meanwhile we moved the product data request to just prior to presenting the in-app storefront - the correct programmatic solution, as suggested by maddy.