# App crashing at startup with iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, startup

I'm new to the site and I wasn't able to figure out how to comment on an existing post (seems like you need a certain amount of reputation, which I don't yet have).

Since the iOS 7.0.3 update I've had a number of users report that the app crashes on start up (generally after completing an in-app purchase).  This thread seems to deal with the same issue:

[SKProductsRequest crashing app at startup with iOS 7.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710264/skproductsrequest-crashing-app-at-startup-with-ios-7-0-3)

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the issue on any of my devices (tried a bunch).  I was wondering if anyone has had a similar problem, or knows how to reproduce the problem above.  My code does request the products on launch, so it seems like that should be the problem, but I'm worried I won't be able to tell if it is fixed because I can't reproduce it internally.

I found some other sites indicating that there could be an issue with certain countries, but I wasn't able to reproduce it by switching my App Store to those countries either.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I found another thread that seems to be related:

[Following in app purchase, app crashing on startup. productIdentifier=nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817130/following-in-app-purchase-app-crashing-on-startup-productidentifier-nil)

If I force my productIdentifier to be nil, I get a crash (that looks similar).  I'm not sure why the productIdentifier would ever be nil though.  To prevent the crash I could (should) check for a nil productIdentifier.  Does anyone know how transaction.payment.productIdentifier or transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier could be nil?

Comment: We have a similar problem, and yet no way to reproduce :( 
The thread you linked is a different issue, they crash because of taking too long to startup the app.

Comment: Thanks Antzi.  I'm glad to hear I'm not alone.  Have you been able to determine any common features of the users that are having problems?  So far all we have is iOS 7.0.3; we've got different countries, different devices.

Comment: Same here. Actually, I think the problem come from a nil string passed to a string formater while using apirater. So maybe not linked to In app purchase. However, they might not be only one bug. It seems to be only 7.0.3 on iphone/ipad.

Comment: Did you get any crash reports?

Comment: We received one crash log, which we've been unable to symbolicate (unfortunately).

Comment: @jareds We apparently have a scenario involving newly created itunes accounts

Comment: @jareds do you link against sdk ios7 or sdk ios6 ?

Comment: @Antzi We're using the iOS 6 SDK in our project.  Which are you using?

Comment: @jareds iOS6 too. We submitted an update following the recommandation to check for nil product identifier. We logged the event with flurry, I will tell you more once it get live on the store.

Comment: @jareds NB: maybe iOS 7.0.4 (out today) will solve the problem... They made tweaks to the in app purchase, even if it's hard to link the bug list to our problem

Answer (score 0):

We submitted an update using this question:
[Following in app purchase, app crashing on startup. productIdentifier=nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817130/following-in-app-purchase-app-crashing-on-startup-productidentifier-nil)

Everything is solved :)

Thanks a lot !